# I don't understand how to use the django 3rd party library djangorestframework-api-key

Tags: django, api, authentication, django-rest-framework, api-key

I'm trying to set up an authentication that requires a user to send an API key and secret in the header of a request before being able to create the data. I'm using djangorestframework-api-key found here: https://florimondmanca.github.io/djangorestframework-api-key/guide/. However, I'm struggling with how to use it properly. My models.py looks something like this:

```
class UserTier(Base):
    key = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    api_key = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    tiers = models.ManyToManyField(Tier)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        api_key, self.api_key = APIKey.objects.create_key(name=self.user.key)
        super(UserTier, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here is an example API endpoint view that I have made:

```
class MLBTeams(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = MLBTeamSerializer
    queryset = Team.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [HasAPIKey]
```

I ran this to get the API Key and passed it through the header in postman:

```
print(APIKey.objects.get_from_key('V9Js7vY7.s1xiK0pWtzbp1ZQA3e2NrT95qhUk1kRV')) #key stored in the UserTier object
```

However, I'm still getting the following error:

```
{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}
```

[image: Screenshot of request]

Does anybody know how to use this library properly?

Comment: When sending a  request, how did you pass the api key?

Comment: Added a screenshot to the post

Comment: Can you try using `V9Js7vY7.s1xiK0pWtzbp1ZQA3e2NrT95qhUk1kRV` as the api key? The api key that needs to be used is the result of `create_key` and not `get_from_key`

Comment: Same 403 forbidden error saying authentication credentials were not provided.